# How do I unprovision default apps in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, powershell

I'm trying to set up computers for the school district I work for and I can't seem to uninstall the default apps for all users. If I use Powershell and run Remove-AppxPackage -Package [packagename] it will remove the files for me, but they list as "staged" for all other users, and running Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -Package [packagename] results in a File Not Found error. When I log in as another user, all the programs are right there in my Start menu again.

How do I remove these apps for all users? I assume I have to unprovision them, but I can't find any documentation how.

Comment: There isn't a method in the current version of Windows 10 that works.  You can simply disable Windows Store applications through a group policy though.

Comment: [Administrative Templates (.admx) for Windows 10](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48257&WT.mc_id=rss_alldownloads_all) is the current version of the policies which works with Version 1511

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is certainly that "**Remove-AppxPackage**" and "**AppxProvisionedPackage**" don't have the same "[**packagename**]" parameter :

For sample, if I want to remove "Alarm" application (on my Windows 10 version), I do for the current user :

```
Remove-AppxPackage -Package Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_10.1702.333.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

and for provisioned apps :

```
Remove-AppxProvisionedPackage -Online -PackageName Microsoft.WindowsAlarms_2017.203.236.0_neutral_~_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

You can list package name for the current user with the following command :

```
Get-AppxPackage -AllUser | Where-Object {$_.PackageUserInformation -like "*Installed*" } | Format-List -Property PackageFullName
```

To list provisioned package names, you can use this command (with administrator rights) :

```
DISM /Online /Get-ProvisionedAppxPackages | select-string Package
```

PS: If someone need to "sysprep" with removed provisioned package, be sure to remove package for the current user too; else sysprep will fail.